# Rails adding extra fileds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

This is my customization for devise registration page:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: {:class => 'text-left'}) do |f| %>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :first_name, 'First Name' %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :first_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :last_name, 'Last Name' %><br />
            <%= f.email_field :last_name, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last Name", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :email, 'Email' %><br />
                    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Password", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password' %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "off", placeholder: "Confirm Password", class: "form-control" %>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default signup-btn">Submit</button>
        <% end %>
```

And following were my `registration_controller.rb`

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

    def create
        @user = User.build(user_params)
        if @user.sign_up
            sign_in_and_redirect(:user, @user)
        end

        logger.info "event=custome registration is successful #{@user}"
    end


    def new
        super
    end

    private 

    def user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name,:last_name, :email, :getting_started, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

end
```

The problem is, in my `User` model I dont have a field for `first_name` and `last_name` but I need user register their `first_name` and `last_name` to the profile page. How can I achieve this, since I receive an error  `undefined method`first_name' for #` when ever I register new user. Thanks

EDIT

user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


  has_one :profile
  delegate :id, to: :person, prefix: true

  has_many :products


  def self.init
    Rails.logger.info("HERE IS INSIDE SELF INIT....")
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)

        where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
        user.email = auth.info.email
        user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
        #user.name = auth.info.name   # assuming the user model has a name
        #user.image = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
      end
    end

  def self.build(opts = {})
    u = User.new(opts.except(:profile, :id))
    u.setup(opts)
    u
  end

  def setup(opts)
    self.email = opts[:email]
    self.valid?
    self.set_profile(Profile.new((opts[:profile] || {}).except(:id)))
    self
  end

  def set_profile(profile)
    logger.info "PROFILE #{profile}"
    self.profile = profile
  end

    def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["raw_info"]
        user.email = data["email"] if user.email.blank?
      end
    end
  end

  def sign_up
      save
  end


end
```

profile model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: Did you create a migration for the fields?

Comment: @DickieBoy, hi my first_name filed are at profile table not user table.

Comment: You should post some more code. Users model and the profile model.

Comment: @DickieBoy ok done. See the edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare first_name and last_name as non-persisted properties on your User model as in:

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
```

And then declare an after_save callback like so:

```
after_save :save_profile

def save_profile
  profile.update(first_name:first_name, last_name:last_name)
end
```

EDIT: You should likely include an if block for the after_save callback, since it may wipe out the profile info if you haven't set the name fields on your user model:

```
after_save :save_profile, if: -> {first_name && last_name}
```

You can use whatever logic works for you here, possibly `{first_name || last_name}` etc.

Comment: Hi, I am getting wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) `app/models/user.rb:43:in `save_profile' `

Comment: This shouldn't happen with a has_one relationship, but it might depend on the Rails version you are using(?).  What happens if you change update to update_all in that method?

Comment: Great.  I'm keeping the original version of the answer because at least in Rails 4 a has_one relationship should return the profile object itself, in which case update should work as described.  In your case it seems to be returning an ActiveRelation object.